# PyQt5 TabWidget tabBarClicked TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying to making a user interface with PyQt5. If i click the 5th index tab userSettings() function will call. But program raises this error:

```
self.tabWidget.tabBarClicked(5).connect(self.userSettings())
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

How can i fix it?

```
import sys
import PyQt5.QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QTabBar, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from numpy import *
from alfa_gui import Ui_MainWindow
    
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.tabWidget.tabBarClicked(5).connect(self.userSettings())

    def userSettings(self):
        
        if self.lineEdit.text() == "cogal" and self.lineEdit_2.text() == "cogal":
            print("Success!")
        else:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("Hatalı Giriş!")
            msg.setText("Wrong Password Or Username")
            x = msg.exec_()  
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = MainWindow()
        window.setWindowTitle('ALFA')
        window.show()
        exit_code = app.exec_()
        sys.exit(exit_code)
```

Comment: For future reference, please try to reduce your code to a [mre]: there are unrequired imports (numpy), and it relies on an UI file you didn't provide. Also, please read more about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. the arguments shown in the signals documentation are the arguments received from the functions they're connected to;
2. signal connections require the *reference* to a callable, while you're calling the desired function (with the parentheses), which would raise a TypeError as the function returns `None`;

Change to:

```
    self.tabWidget.tabBarClicked.connect(self.userSettings)
```

And then:

```
def userSettings(self, tabIndex):
    if tabIndex != 5:
        return
    # ...
```

Note that you should connect to the [`currentChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#currentChanged) signal, not the `tabBarClicked` one, as that will be triggered anyway even if the clicked tab is already the current one.

Comment: How does `tabIndex` argument passed to `userSettings` by `connect`?

Comment: @MSH that's how signals and slots work: the *argument* shown in each signal documentation is what is passed to the connected function. In this case, [`tabBarClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#tabBarClicked) has an *index* argument, which is what is passed to `userSettings`. Arguments can be ignored, but since they're provided (and they usually are required for the called function), you should use them instead of calling the "getter" function for the same argument value.

Comment: Wow. That is something new for me. Apparently I need to read more. :)

Comment: it worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the `tabWidget.tabBarClicked` is not callable.

I would connect a listener to `tabWidget`'s `onchange`:

```
self.tabWidget.currentChanged.connect(self.function_to_run)
```

Then you can write your `function_to_run` to check the `currentIndex()`

```
...
self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.function_to_run)
...
def function_to_run(self):
    if self.tabWidget.currentIndex() == 5:
        print("Do stuff")
```

Comment: It's not just `tabBarClicked` that isn't callable: *no* signal is callable at all. The OP can still use `tabBarClicked` signal, the problem is that it shouldn't be *called* and that the connection argument must be a callable.